# Using MVC with multi-table data

Tags: mvc

I read a few articles and Stack posts but I'm still unsure how to use MVC properly.

One of my app features is handling meetings - each having a list of subjects to discuss. My database tables look like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE meetings (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  moderator varchar(128),
)
CREATE TABLE meeting_subjects (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  meetingd_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  order int(11) NOT NULL,
  subject varchar(128) NOT NULL,
)
```

My controller allows browsing and creating new meetings.

I don't know how to properly design controller and model. I'd like to ask few questions that should help me use a proper MVC design:

1. Should I have one or two models?

   - It seems having model per tabale could fit the definition of [anemic domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) anti-pattern. I don't expect to work with `meeting_subjects` on their own.
   - On the other hand when using model per table I could gain from my framework helpers (it happens to be `CodeIgniter\Model` providing CRUD methods).
2. How to handle input data in a controller?

   - Should my controller deal with meeting vs. subjects separately?
     `$meeting_id = $meetingsModel->addMeeting($_POST['date'], $_POST['moderator']);`
     `$meetingsModel / $subjectsModel->addSubjects($meeting_id, $_POST['subjects']);`
   - Or should I rather have a single model method and pass all data to it?
     `$meetingsModel->addMeeting($_POST['date'], $_POST['moderator'], $_POST['subjects']);`
3. [optional] In case of two models and controller calling one method: I assume it's fine to call subjects model method from meeting model method?

Answer (score 2):

[MVC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is an architectural pattern that was invented at the time GUI started to emerge and there was a need to separate concerns in order to keep the rich applications maintainable.  So the focus of this pattern is on the separation into three main components, without many details about their inner structures. Keeping this in mind, it’ one model, one controller and several views.

One model doesn’t mean one entity or table. Model is an abstraction for whatever you’re dealing with. So you can have many tables belonging to a model. And large models can be subdivided into domains.  So from MVC perspective a single M doesn’t mean a single class, but whatever diverse class you need in your domain model. It may be noted that the [initial publications](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html) used a potentially more restrictive understanding of the model (i.e. model abjects and aggregates) and used a many to many relation between models and clusters made of one controller with several views. But the more general meaning of domain model set through in most architecural work since then (e.g. [Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html))

Nowadays, there are a lot more variants around MVC. But unless you are creating a rich client with a remote database, I’d rather suggest to consider more modern evolutions of MVC:

- [MVP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter): The P becomes the single channel between M and V, being understood that it could be split-up in a server part (managing the model) interrelated with a client part (managing the user)
- [MVVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel): The view is empowered to manage all the GUI (like it’s done in most modern GUIs) interactions with the user. It communicates with a view-model interacts that serves as bridge with the model.

But in all cases what I said above about single M and multiple entities still holds.